# BASH: split string on \n and store in array

Tags: bash

I have the following string that I read in from a file in bash

```
BOB_ENV: DEV\nStorage: @MOM.KV(Name=lol-lol;SCT=c-s-string)\nConn__name: ab-cb-ac-one.sb.w.net\nTest: Test
```

I am trying to make the \n the delimiter and store into an array

I am not sure if I am doing it properly but I have the following script

```
test="BOB_ENV: DEV\nStorage: @MOM.KV(Name=lol-lol;SCT=c-s-string)\nConn__name: ab-cb-ac-one.sb.w.net\nTest: Test"
arr=(`echo $test`)
echo ${arr[1]}
```

right now it splits the string on the spaces I have in the string and stores into the array.  I want to split on the \n in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf '%b'` to interpret `\n` as line break and read it into array using `readarray`:

```bash
s='BOB_ENV: DEV\nStorage: @MOM.KV(Name=lol-lol;SCT=c-s-string)\nConn__name: ab-cb-ac-one.sb.w.net\nTest: Test'

# read into array
readarray -t arr < <(printf '%b\n' "$s")

# check array content
declare -p arr
```

**Output:**

> `declare -a arr=([0]="BOB_ENV: DEV" [1]="Storage: @MOM.KV(Name=lol-lol;SCT=c-s-string)" [2]="Conn__name: ab-cb-ac-one.sb.w.net" [3]="Test: Test")`